# Why it is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

my question is very simple.

It is Given $X$, $Y$ Banach Spaces and a sequence of bounded linear operators $T_{n}$ such that $T_{n} x$ converges to $T x$ in $Y$ for all $x \in X$.

I proved that T is linear but I do not know why I can say: "for each $x \in X$, the sequence ${T_{n} x}$ is bounded since it converges".

I need to prove this to be able to use the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: All but a finite number of elements live in your favorite ball centered at $Tx$...

Answer (score 0):

Because the numbers $a_{n}=||T_{n}x||_{Y}<\infty$ for every $n$ and there are only a finite number of $a_{n}$ whereby for any $\epsilon>0$ given $|a_{n}-a|<\epsilon$ fails ($|a|=||\lim T_{n}x||$).  Taking the maximum of these finite $a_{n}$ gives you the radius of a ball about the point $\lim T_{n}x$ that contains all of the $\{T_{n}x\}_{n}.$

Comment: Why are there only a finite number of $a_{n}$? why all of them cannot be different?

Comment: Sorry, I realized that this finite values are outside of the ball. Thanks.